# JQuery changing element's predefined style by changing attribute doesn't work in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I have a few predefined styles in my css based on an elements attribute. If i update the attribute's value to something new that also has a predefined style the style is applied in FF and Chrome but not IE. See example and type in input field please.

JS:

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(){
    var l = parseInt($(this).attr('level'), 10) + 1;
    $(this).attr('level', l);
});
```

CSS:

```
input[level="0"]{background:red;}
input[level="1"]{background:blue;}
input[level="2"]{background:green;}
input[level="3"]{background:black;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ce6S4/

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

EDIT: 
works with IE 9 but not <= 8

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added, sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an IE-bug. Notice that the element is rendered correctly when you resize the window.

Trigger the reflow by setting the class name:

```
this.className = this.className; // Or .addClass(' ');
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ce6S4/6/

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(){
    var l = parseInt($(this).attr('level'), 10) + 1;
    $(this).attr('level', l).addClass(' ');
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir this has fixed the problem.

Comment: why do you highlight the link ?  we can understand it also without "<b>" ...:)

Comment: @RoyiNamir I alway highlight my demo link above the code, so that the demo can be found more easily. In large answers, it may be hard to find the necessary information among the walls of text/code blocks. Here's how I see non-highlighted text+link between code blocks: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YcUdG.png

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ce6S4/3/

try this

```
   $('input').on('keydown', function(){
         var l = parseInt($(this).attr('level'), 10) + 1;
    alert(l); //can be removed.
         $(this).attr('level', l.toString()).hide().show().focus();

});​
```

Comment: I'd already deleted my comment. Why not just do it at the outset?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Thanks for the input, but this seems to break functionality in all browsers for me.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: The hide/show is a good idea, but messes up focus. If you try to restore focus, the cursor placement gets messed up.